# Does symmetric difference, coupled with an intersection, respect negation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To give an explicit example, for arbitrary real sets A, B, and C, does $(-A \cap -B) \Delta -C = -((A \cap B) \Delta C)$ where $-X = \left\{ -x:x \in X \right\}$?

Comment: What do you think?  Have you tried any examples?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Right now, this question is likely to be flagged as low quality because you don't appear to have put any effort into solving the problem yourself. Please edit the question with details of what you've tried and how you got stuck in order to avoid downvotes.